# Ubuntu почему команда выполняется в command-line, но не в crontab -e?

Tags: ubuntu

Мне нужно чтобы файл запускался следующим образом:

```
nohup python3 -u /home/Test/main.py > /home/Test/logs/output_$(date "+%T_%d_%m_%Y").out &
```

Все работает хорошо, я добавляю задание в `crontab -e`:

```
*/3 * * * * nohup python3 -u /home/Test/main.py > /home/Test/logs/output_$(date "+%T_%d_%m_%Y").out &
```

Но оно не хочет работать, как только убираю форматирование даты, то начинает работать. Что я делаю не так? Мне нужно, чтобы в названии файла была текущая дата и время.
Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 2):

Дату в кронтаб можно поставить таким образом

```
DATE=date +%F
BACKPATH=/backup/pg/1c83/

# m h  dom mon dow    command
  0 6  *   *   *      pg_basebackup ... --pgdata=$BACKPATH$($DATE)/pg_basebackup/
```